# Create innerHTML and retrieve its HTML

Tags: javascript

I create Google chart base64 image `<img src="data:image/png;base64, ivbO...">`:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(my_chart, 'ready', function () {
   chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + my_chart.getImageURI() + '">';
});
```

But when I want to retrieve the html of this div and the image for later use like so:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var html_data = document.getElementById('img_container');
   console.log(html_data.innerHTML);
}, false);
```

I only get empty div without the image `<img src="data:image/png;base64, ivbO...">`

ID is correct and all other markup so no mistake there.

Comment: Thats a racing problem. The page loads faster than the google charts api.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML doesn't get set until the Google Chart Ready event fires. That happens *after* the document's DOMContentLoaded event.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(my_chart, 'ready', function () {
   chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + my_chart.getImageURI() + '">';
   var html_data = document.getElementById('img_container');
   console.log(html_data.innerHTML);
});
```

Comment: any solution other than above one? Basicly I want to get contents of the entire page after it has loaded and after the google API finished its work.